# Oracle Reports Service Filename in Cache ( Desname )

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle10g, oraclereports

When I run report, a pdf file is generated in Oracle Reports Service Cache. Although I specify "DESNAME" like this:

```
SRW.ADD_PARAMETER (V_Paramlist, 'DESNAME', 'Test');
```

Generated pdf file name is: 'Testjn2iS6m.pdf' What is "jn2iS6m"? Where come it from? How can I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/bi.1012/b14048/pbr_cla.htm#i637000) says DESNAME may be overridden by your operating system, which might be what's happening here. I would suggest changing the value of DESNAME to include both the path where you want the file to save as well as the extension of the file. You'll have to make sure Reports has access to write to the specified directory, which differs between versions 6i/10g/12c.

For example (for Windows):

```
SRW.ADD_PARAMETER (V_Paramlist, 'DESNAME', 'c:\temp\test.pdf');
```

Comment: I changed it as to include path. And result "testb1o6GO1C.pdf". It is Linux

Comment: What did you set as the parameter? Did you add the extension as well? If so and it still added the characters then it appears something in your operating system is causing the filename, rather than Oracle Reports, per the documentation.